# Dynamic Receiver in Powermail (6.0.0) based on String

Tags: typo3-8.x, powermail

TYPO3 8.7.x, Powermail 6.0.0

I'd like to override the receiver based on two subjects they can select.

Now I know that this works just fine:

```
[globalString = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|konsilbereich = 5]
```

But this does not seem to work:

```
[globalString = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|konsilbereich = "Some phrase"]
```

I read that some workarounds were to have a hidden field that's been filled by Javascript upon a users selection and instead of the actual field, the hidden field gets submitted. But that is not an option for us.

I checked the docs as well as many support forums but could not find a good answer to this.

Is this not possible, or if, how would I accomplish that I can use an actual string within the comparison?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a comparisation with a string in TypoScript conditions. Strings could have space, special characters or umlauts. That's why TypoScript works best with integers.

Two possibilities come into my mind for your case:

1) Building an own conditition is quite simple in TYPO3 (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/Conditions/Reference.html#custom-conditions for an easy example)

2) Use an integer together with GP: - but then I would use a selectbox with a text as label and a number as value